# How to restore matlab random generator state into numpy?

Tags: numpy, matlab, numpy-random

I can save the state of matlab random generator with the following code

```
seed = 10;
rng(seed, 'twister');
%... random functions that don't need to be reproduced%

s = rng;
s.Type
s.Seed
s.State
save('rand_state.mat', 's');

%... random functions that need to be reproduced%
```

How would you import the *state* of the Mersenne Twister into numpy so that it generates the same random numbers after it was saved?

Just using `np.random.RandomState(seed)` does not take into account that the state of the twister was modified by the subsequent random calls before it was saved.

Comment: Maybe start here: https://walkingrandomly.com/?p=5479. But also consider if you actually need to perfectly replicate the actual random variates for your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

np.random.RandomState has a function [set_state()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.RandomState.set_state.html#numpy.random.RandomState.set_state) that takes the input `state = ('MT19937', keys, pos)`

The only gotcha is that matlab saves pos as the last element of State. The rest are the keys that set_state expects.

```
rng = np.random.RandomState(s['Seed'])
rng.set_state("MT19937", s['State'], s['State'][-1])
```

I learned the hard way that that matlab and python use different transformations to convert random draws from [0,1) into integers or normal variates. So one will have to write custom functions for ints and normals in matlab, if that needs to be replicated in python.